# Multidimensional array with unknown items

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, console

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int *width;
int *height;
int row;
int column;
int character;
int count;
int pictureit;
double i = 0;
FILE *fp;


char file[50]; 
char line[25]; // assume each line has max 25 characters 

printf("What file should we pull from: ");
scanf("%s", file);

//read file using File pointer

fp = fopen(file, "r");

// read the first line in the file 
fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);

width = strtok(line,"x");
height = strtok(NULL, "/0");


// read all the future lines in the file excluding the first 
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {

row = strtok(line, ",");
column = strtok(NULL, ",");
character = strtok(NULL, ",");
count = strtok(NULL, "/0");


if(i < count) {


**printf("%s", pictureit[row][column] = character);**

i++;

}
}
fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

I'm pulling in a file with this kind of setup

```
75x53
0,36,.,1
0,37,M,1
1,32,.,1
1,33,:,1
1,34,A,1
1,35,M,2
1,37,O,1
1,38,:,1
2,23,.,1
2,24,:,1
2,25,A,1
2,26,M,5
```

I've been brainstorming for a while. How would I go about displaying this on the console? It obviously needs to go into a 2d array. The program needs to know the height and width of the array to display a space or character in that spot.

PS: This program will display a picture in the console when finished. The "** **" is where I am working.

Comment: Please ally proper formating!

Comment: I do not see any git pull. What do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change sequential numbers (ex: 0, 36,.,1) to items (ex: row, column, character, count)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214251/how-to-change-sequential-numbers-ex-0-36-1-to-items-ex-row-column-char)

Comment: Indentation, [redacted]. Do you use it?

Comment: What is the 4th value for?

Comment: One of the more or less rare cases where the use of `fscanf()` seems appropriate to me. No need to wildly `strtok()` around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could dynamically allocate a 2d array with the right dimensions (according to your first line), then fill it up with the data from your file and finally print it with two nested for loops.

EDIT: Basically, you would do:

```
//...

//Create the dynamic array
char ** array = malloc(sizeof(char) * height);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * width);

// Fill your array here (put different chars in it) ...

//Print it
int x,y;
for(y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(x = 0; x < width; x++)
        printf("%c ", array[y][x]);

    printf("\n");
}

//Free the array
for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    free(array[i]);
free(array);
```

I voluntarily omitted the part where you check the return value of the malloc (whether it's NULL or not), but you should definitely add it.

Comment: Why a (complicate) "scattered array", which infact isn't a real 2D-array, but a 1D pointer array? A simple `char (*p)[width][heigth] = malloc(sizeof *p);` would do as well. Access the elements as `(*p)[x][y] = '.';`.

Comment: And assuming >=C99 it is as easy as `char a[width][height];` not need allocate dynamically at all.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I wouldn't do this, but I felt the need to do a scanning exercise:

```
int main(void)
{
  char fn[100];
  fprintf(stdout, "Enter file name:");
  fflush(stdout);
  int result = fscanf(stdin, " %99s", fn);
  if (1 != result)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Reading the file's name failed.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  {
    size_t width= 0;
    size_t height 0;

    FILE * pf = fopen(fn, "r");
    if (NULL == pf)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Opening file '%s' failed.\n", fn);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    {
      result = fscanf(pf, " %zux%zu", &width, &height);
      if (2 != result)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Reading width and/or heigth from file '%s' failed.\n", fn);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      {
        char (*pa)[width][height] = calloc(1, sizeof *pa);
        if (NULL == pa)
        {
          perror("calloc() failed");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        {
          size_t number_of_rows = width * height;

          fprintf(stderr, "Trying to read %zu data rows.\n", number_of_rows);

          for (size_t row = 0; row < number_of_rows; ++row)
          {
            size_t x, y;
            char c;
            int i;
            result = fscanf(pf, " %zu,%zu,%c,%d", &x, &y, &c, &i);
            if (4 != result)
            {
              fprintf(stderr, "Reading data (#%zu) row from '%s' failed.\n", row, fn);
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            /* Add check here to avoid accessing the array out-of-bounds! */
            (*pa)[x][y] = c;
          }
        }

        {
          for (size_t row = 0; row < width; ++row)
          {
            for (size_t column = 0; column < height; ++column)
            {
              fprintf(stdout, "%c", (*pa)[row][column]);
            }

            fprintf(stdout, "\n");
          }
        }

        free(pa);
      }
    }

    fclose(pf);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also I am curious about the picture to be printed ... ;-)